# remove a key if value matches a pattern?

Tags: php, regex

i've got an array with string values.

i want to search for a pattern with regex and if matched, remove the key containing the value.

how would i accomplish this?

Comment: What is the input array? What is the desired outout? What is the pattern? What have you tried? Too vague, no [mcve]. Unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

preg_grep: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

```
$a = array('foo' => 'xx', 'bar' => '12');
$b = preg_grep('~[a-z]~', $a, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
print_r($b);
```