# How to remove key value pairs from a PHP array if the key contains (matches) one or more substrings

Tags: php, regex, arrays, filter

I have an large array like (simplified for convenience):

```
Array
(
    [last_name] => Ricardo 
    [first_name] => Montalban
    [sex] => Yes please
    [uploader_0_tmpname] => p171t8kao6qhj1132l14upe14rh1.jpg
    [uploader_0_name] => IMAG0114-1.jpg
    [uploader_0_status] => done
    [uploader_count] => 1
    [captcha_uid] => 155
)
```

And wish to remove all key value pairs where the key starts with `uploader_` (this can be a series) and also every occurrence of `captcha_uid`.

I've seen a useful example here:
[remove a key if value matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304470/remove-a-key-if-value-matches-a-pattern)
but I'm terrible at regular expressions. How to optimally do this? Your views are much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions in such a simple case. Applying the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304474/502381) in the other question:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if( strpos( $key, 'uploader_' ) === 0 ) {
        unset( $array[ $key ] );
    }
}

unset( $array[ 'captcha_uid' ] );
```

Comment: Thank you. Although the other answers will also work, I accepted this one because you explicitly did not use regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

try this one :

```
$data = array(
    'last_name' => 'Ricardo',
    'first_name' => 'Montalban',
    'sex' => 'Yes please',
    'uploader_0_tmpname' => 'p171t8kao6qhj1132l14upe14rh1.jpg',
    'uploader_0_name' => 'IMAG0114-1.jpg',
    'uploader_0_status' => 'done',
    'uploader_count' => '1',
    'captcha_uid' => '155',
);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/uploader_(.*)/s', $key)) {
        unset($data[$key]);
    }
}
unset($data['captcha_uid']);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your very complete answer, it gives me a better insight in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `foreach` with the PHP function `preg_match`. Something like that.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if(!preg_match("#^uploader_#", $key)) {
    unset($array[$key]);  
  }
}
```

Comment: `preg_match` is pointless complexity here, why not use `strpos`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gives me a better insight in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.6.0 (`ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`) you can also do this way:

```
$myarray = array_filter( $myarray, function ( $key ) {
    return 0 !== strpos( $key, 'uploader_' ) && 'captcha_uid' != $key;
} , ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );
```

Ref: [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)